# How do I create custom generated reports of various length?

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to create a standardized form in Excel for data that I pull from other workbooks.

I would like to automatically generate the form (Report Sheet) based on the data provided in a separate sheet (Data Sheet).  I figure this would be simpler that writing a script to pull individual information from several workbooks.

My problem is that the number of records (rows) are variant.  I cannot simply map the cells from the Data sheet to the Report sheet because for some reports there will be 20 rows, some will be 8, etc.

What would be the simplest way to accomplish this?  I'm stuck on how to create a macro that would check how many rows are on the data sheet and create that corresponding number on the report sheet selecting only the pre-determine fields that I want.

I realize this can be accomplished much easier in Access, but I do not have Access.

Thanks for the input.

Comment: Is the data contiguous ? i.e. `set myrange = Range("a1", Range("a1").end(xlDown)): myrange.Select` selects all contiguous cells in a1

Comment: you should really use xlUp in case there is any blank cells in column A |  


                set myrange = Range("a1", Range("a65536").end(xlUp))

Comment: Yes, the data is contiguous.  So what would I do in this case?  For Each Row in Selection insert row and copy the following data to the cell.  Does that sound about right?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have the right idea with having a data sheet and a seperate report sheet which displays the required data in a suitable format.

*"I cannot simply map the cells from the Data sheet to the Report sheet because for some reports there will be 20 rows, some will be 8, etc."*

Im not sure what you mean by this, are you saying that the rows on the data sheet can grow and shrink in size?  Or are you saying you want the end user to be able to select the rows they want on the report?  In other words what determines which rows you want on the report?

Aside from this, firstly you want to work with the cell values only, this way when copying them to your report sheet all formatting on your report sheet is retained.

As far as transferring the data there are a number of ways using vba to do it depending on your answer to my question above.

- Advance filter the rows based on a criteria (using the copy to another location)
- Copy all rows the user has selected (should be no need to use a loop, For Each Row etc)
- Copy the rows based on a user input box where the user enters the rows required.

I would suggest copying all columns and then hiding the columns you don't require:

```
Worksheets("Report").Range("B:B,D:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  To answer your question, the needed data will be manually entered into separate tabs, and data from all these rows would be pulled into the report.  Effectively, the user will be copying and pasting the chosen rows into the separate tabs.  I'm thinking I would HAVE to use a VBA macro to create several new rows dependent on how many records it finds in the other sheets.  Also, I can't simply copy and paste the column and then hide the unneeded ones because a lot of the values in the report are formula-driven.